# InDesign search filename on multiple documents

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to make a script in JavaScript, but I'm not very experienced in this field, so I'm here to seek help.

Basically where I work I have a ton of .indd files with a lot of different images with different names and numbers every day.
When someone want to know in which document is a certain image I need to search manually for every image.

I'm trying to put together a working script, but without any luck.
What I'm looking for is a script that let you select a folder, let you type the name (or part of the name) of the filename to search for, search through all the documents in the folder without opening all the files at once (for performance reason as the files are a lot), and give you an alert if the file with that name is found.

I have merged together various scripts found on various sites, but it doesn't work for some unknown reason.

The code is the following

```js
    app.scriptPreferences.enableRedraw = false;
    var Directory = Folder.selectDialog ("Seleziona una cartella");
    if (!Directory) {
        exit();
        }
    var Documents = Directory.getFiles();
    var Dialwindow = new Window("dialog");
    Dialwindow.text = "Search";
    Dialwindow.orientation = "column";
    var Textbar = Dialwindow.add('edittext');
    Textbar.preferredSize.width = 150;
    Textbar.active = true
    var Buttons = Dialwindow.add("group", undefined);
    Buttons.orientation = "row";
    var Search = Buttons.add("button", undefined, undefined);
    Search.text = "Search";
    Search.onClick = function() {
        Dialwindow.close();
        }
    var Exit = Buttons.add("button", undefined, undefined);
    Exit.text = "Exit";
    Exit.onClick = function() {

// So far, so good, now I'm looking for a code that stops the script completely, as at the moment clicking on Search or Exit gives the same result

        Dialwindow.close();
        }
    Dialwindow.show();
    for (var i = 0; i < Documents.length; i++) {

// Now I think it begins the part that gives me problem

        app.open(Documents[i]);

// As far as I understand this opens every indd files one by one

            Collegamenti = app.activeDocument.links;
            Result = Textbar.text;

// This script was found on a site. Normally it works, but merging it doesn't

            var Array = new Array();
            for(var i=0; i < Collegamenti.length; i++) {
                var Nome = Collegamenti[i].name;
                Nome = Nome.toLowerCase();
                if(Nome.indexOf(Result.toLowerCase()) != -1)Array.push(Collegamenti[i]);
                }

// I'm not sure if this is written correctly

            if (Array.length= 1) {
                alert("You can find the image " + Result + " in this file " + app.activeDocument.name.replace(/.[^.]+$/,''));
                app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.NO);
                }
            else {
                app.activeDocument.close(SaveOptions.NO);
                }
        }
```

So this script should let you select a folder, create a dialog window with a text bar, search through the documents in the folder, if an image with that name is found trigger an alert, else close the document.

I thank anyone who can explain what is wrong or can suggest improvements/corrections.
If something is not clear due to my bad English, please ask, I'll try to be more clear.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks Yuri for your quick answer, I have learned a few new things from your code (like the "while() {}" and the ".shift" parts that I didn't know about).
Unfortunately, where I work, it's not very practical to scroll all the txt file to find what I was searching (as there are a lot of indd files), even if your script saves me from wasting a lot of time.
I apologize but I have probably not been very clear, as my intent was to understand what is wrong with the original code, so I could learn instead of having some ready-to-go code.
The parts I don't understand are:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < Documents.length; i++) {
        app.open(Documents[i]);
```

This opens all the documents, one by one which is essentially correct, but I can't use app.activeDocument.links; because there is no active document.
There is a way to use a variable instead of app.activeDocument.links with the code above?
I've tried to use the "while (Documents.length) {var Shift = Documents.shift();var Doc = app.open(Shift);" but for the same reason I don't know how to continue with the next code.
Another thing is this:

```
    var Array = new Array();
    var Links = app.activeDocument.links
        for(var i=0; i < Links.length; i++) {
            var Name = Links[i].name;
            Name = Name.toLowerCase();
            if(Name.indexOf(Textbar.text.toLowerCase()) != -1)Array.push(Links[i]);
            }
```

It works with all the documents opened, but I don't know how use it with the "app.open(Documents[i]);" as there is no active document opened.
And there is a way to stop the script with the Button.onClick = function() {}? I've tried exit(); but it doesn't work.

---

**EDIT2**

Thanks to Yuri, this is the final code:

```
    app.scriptPreferences.enableRedraw = false;
    app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevels.NEVER_INTERACT;
    var folder = Folder.selectDialog ("Select a folder");
    if (!folder) exit();
    var files = folder.getFiles('*.indd');
    if (files.length == 0) { alert("The folder doesn\'t contain any indd files"); exit() }
    var name = prompt("Write a file name:");
    if (name == null) { alert("Empty textbar"); exit() }
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    var total = [];
    while (files.length) {
        var doc = app.open(files.shift());
        var links = doc.links.everyItem().getElements();
        if (links.length == 0) { alert("No links are present in document\r''" + doc.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '') + "''");}
        var find = [];
        while (links.length) {
            var link = links.shift();
            if (link.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name) > -1) {find.push(link); total.push(link);}}
        if (find.length > 0) { alert("The link ''" + name + "'' is\ron ''" + doc.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '') + "''");}
        doc.close();}
    alert("Done\r" + total.length + " links found");
```

Comment: Does your scrip work? Since for example the line `var Array = new Array();` gets me error. `Array` is a reserved word, you can't use it. Next: the condition `if (Array.length= 1)` it true always, probably there should be `==` or `>` instead of `=`. The line `Directory.getFiles()` gets you all the files in the directory, if there are no .indd files it will get you error if you try to open non indd file. And there is nothing wrong with `app.activeDocument.links` the active document is the document that was opened with `app.open()` command.

Comment: And you're using the variable `i` as a counter for the outer loop and the same variable `i` as a counter for the inner loop. It doesn't make sense. This is exactly why I prefer use loops without counter whenever it's possible.

Comment: It worked due to the fact english is not my language, so I rename the variables in english on the fly. The original wasn't "var Array" but "var Risultato". Thanks, I understood where my mistakes were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code contains too much errors it's hard to explain every single one of them. I've tried fix the errors and keep your algorithm more or less intact. Here is the working code:

```
var directory = Folder.selectDialog("Seleziona una cartella");
if (!directory) exit();

// dialog window -------------------------------------------------------
var dialwindow = new Window("dialog", "Search");

    var textbar = dialwindow.add('edittext');
        textbar.preferredSize.width = 150;
        textbar.active = true

    var buttons = dialwindow.add("group", undefined);
        buttons.orientation = "row";

    var search = buttons.add("button", undefined, "Search");
    var cancel = buttons.add("button", undefined, "Exit");

dialwindow.defaultElement = search;
dialwindow.cancelElement  = cancel;

if (dialwindow.show() != 1) exit();

// main code -----------------------------------------------------------
var result = textbar.text;
var documents = directory.getFiles('*.indd');

for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
    var doc = app.open(documents[i]);
    var links = doc.links;
    var arr = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
        var link_name = links[j].name.toLowerCase();
        if (link_name.indexOf(result.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            arr.push(links[j]);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (arr.length > 0) {
        alert("You can find the image " + result + " in this file " + doc.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, ''));
    }

    doc.close(SaveOptions.NO);
}
```

Comment: Thak you, I get where my errors were. It works perfectly.
I'll try to understand why it was "discarded" the ".onClick = function()" and was adopted "dialwindow.defaultElement".
One last question, there is a way to tell how many times in total the "arr.push(links[j])" is called?
This to have a final alert with the total links found.
I have tried with "arr.length", but it seems related to the last link found and not the total ones.

Comment: In this code I break the loop as soon as the first link witn 'name' is found. So the length of the `arr` is 1 or 0 (if nothing was found). If you want to get all the links that contain 'name' you can remove the `break` statement.

Comment: I was referring to the total links found on all the documents opened. If I remove the break statement and add an alert on the end of the script, it count only the links on the last document opened.

Comment: Of course! The array `arr` is defined as a new empty array `[]` within the loop. If you want to collect all links for all files you have to more the line `var arr = [];` outside of the outer loop. For example you can put it right after the line `var documents = directory.getFiles()`.

Comment: If I move (I believe you meant to write move) the "var arr = [];" outside of the loop, the script finds the image I search for in the document where it actually is, and in every document opened after it (even if the image is not present).

Comment: (yes, I meant 'move') Well, it's seems there is another problem, indeed. As soon as the first image is found the array get a length more than zero and you're getting the alert window on the every iteration of the outer loop. You need to change the condition for alert window then. Etc. But actually it looks exactly like a bad pattern (alert window, etc) entails many unexpected troubles as soon as you try to improve it a bit. I'd advice to use my first code instead.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it to work by adding an array at the beginning and adding a second .push() to the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var file_prefs = 'find_links.json';
var prefs = load_prefs();

main();

function main() {

    // get all indd files from the folder
    var folder = get_folder();
    prefs.folder = folder.fullName;
    var files = get_files(folder);
    if (files.length == 0) { alert('The folder doesn\'t contain any indd files'); exit() }

    // get the link name to search for
    var name = prompt("Write a file name:", prefs.name);
    if (name == null) exit();
    prefs.name = name;

    var report = ['Folder: ' + folder.fsName];
    report.push(['Search for: ' + name]);
    name = name.toLowerCase();

    // search the name among of the links of every indd document
    while (files.length) {
        var doc = app.open(files.shift());
        report.push('\n' + doc.name);

        var links = doc.links.everyItem().getElements();
        while (links.length) {
            var link = links.shift();
            if (link.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name) > -1)
                report.push(link.filePath);
        }

        doc.close();
    }

    // save the report in a text file and open the file
    var report_file = File(folder + '/report.txt');
    report_file.encoding = 'utf-8';
    report_file.open('w');
    report_file.write(report.join('\n'));
    report_file.close();
    if (report_file.exists) report_file.execute();

}

save_prefs();

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function load_prefs() {
    var file = File(Folder.temp + '/' + file_prefs);
    if (!file.exists) return { folder: '', name: '' }
    return $.evalFile(file);
}

function save_prefs() {
    var file = File(Folder.temp + '/' + file_prefs);
    file.encoding = 'utf-8';
    file.open('w');
    file.write(prefs.toSource());
}

function get_folder() {
    if (prefs.folder != '') { var folder = Folder(prefs.folder) }
    else { var folder = new Folder() }
    return folder.selectDlg();
}

function get_files(folder) {
    var files = folder.getFiles('*.indd');
    files = files.sort(sortFileNames);
    return files;
}

// additional function to correct sorting
// https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/help-tweaking-indesign-script-to-alphabetize-imagecatalog-jsx/td-p/10812327
function sortFileNames( a,b ) {

    a = a.name;
    b = b.name;

    var myRegExp = new RegExp('^\\d+');
    var aObj = {num: a.match(myRegExp) != null ? a.match(myRegExp)[0] : '_', string: a.replace(/^\d+/, '')};
    var bObj = {num: b.match(myRegExp) != null ? b.match(myRegExp)[0] : '_', string: b.replace(/^\d+/, '')};

    // a and b are fully numeric :
    if (aObj.string =='' && bObj.string == '') return a - b;

    // the numeric parts of a and b are equal :
    if (aObj.num == bObj.num ) return aObj.string.toLowerCase() > bObj.string.toLowerCase();

    // the numeric part of a is greater than the numeric part of b :
    if (aObj.num > bObj.num ) return 1 ;
};
```

The script asks folder and file name (or part of the name), the open all indd files in the given folder and find the given name among links of each of the indd files. Then it saves report in file 'report.txt' (into the same folder) and open the txt file.

Comment: Thanks, I have answered editing the main post

Comment: If you don't like the report you can change this part of the code any way you like. Say the report could contain only the names of indd files that have the given link. It would be me much shorter. I think a static text report is more convenient than dozens alert windows.